# How signin-google in asp.net core authentication is linked to the google handler?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I went into the source code but I can't see where it's wired to the handler.
In the GoogleExtensions.cs file, I see the

```
 => builder.AddOAuth<GoogleOptions, GoogleHandler>(authenticationScheme,
                                                   displayName, configureOptions);
```

But I don't understand how the route "/signin-google" calls the handler.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How signin-google in asp.net core authentication is linked to the google handler?

The question can be divided into two small questions .

1. How user is redirected to the url of `/signin-google`
2. How `GoogleHandler` process the request on `/signin-google`

#### How user is redirected to `signin-google`

Initially, when user clicks the `Google` button to login with Google Authentication, the browser will post a request to the following url:

```
https://your-server/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F
```

Your server simply redirects the user to Google.com and asks Google to authenticate the current user :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
    response_type=code
    &client_id=xxx
    &scope=openid%20profile%20email
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyour-server%2Fsignin-google
    &state=xxx
```

When Google has authenticated the user successfully, it will redirect the user to your website with a parameter of `code` according to `redirect_uri` above.

```
 https://your-server/signin-google?
    state=xxx
    &code=yyy
    &scope=zzz
    &authuser=0
    &session_state=abc
    &prompt=none
```

Note **the path here equals `/signin-google`.**  That's the first key point.

#### How `GoogleHandler` process the `signin-google`

Before we talk about how `GoogleHandler` goes , we should take a look at how `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `AuthenticationHandler` work:

1. When there's an incoming request, the `AuthenticationMiddleware` (which is registered by `UseAuthentication()` in your `Configure()` method of `Startup.cs`), will inspect every request and try to authenticate user.
2. Since you've configured authentication services to use google authentication , the `AuthenticationMiddleware` will [invoke the **`GoogleHandler.HandleRequestAsync()`** method](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L45)
3. If needed, the [`GoogleHandler.HandleRequestAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L43) then [handle remote authentication with OAuth2.0 protocol](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthHandler.cs#L45) , and get the user's identity.

Here **the `GoogleHandler` inherits from `RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` , and its `HandleRequestAsync()` method will be used by `AuthenticationMiddleware` to determine if need to handle the request.** . When it returns `true`, that means the current request has been already processed by the authentication handler and there's no further process will be executed.

So how does the `HandleRequestAsync()` determine whether the request should be processed by itself ?

**The `HandleRequestAsync()` method  just checks the current path against the `Options.CallbackPath`** . See source code below :

```
public abstract class RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions> : AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>, IAuthenticationRequestHandler
    where TOptions : RemoteAuthenticationOptions, new()
{
   // ...

   public virtual Task<bool> ShouldHandleRequestAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(Options.CallbackPath == Request.Path);

    public virtual async Task<bool> HandleRequestAsync()
    {
        if (!await ShouldHandleRequestAsync())
        {
            return false;
        }
        // ... handle remote authentication , such as exchange code from google
    }
}
```

#### Closing

The whole workflow will be :

1. The user clicks on button to login with Google
2. Google authenticates the user and redirects him to `/signin-google`
3. Since the path== `signin-google`, the middleware will use `HandleRequestAsync()` to proecess current request, and exchange code with google.
4. ... do some other things

Comment: but how it calls to the callback url? In my case signin-google creates the cookies but, as I'm with angular frontend, never reaches a valid callback or the url that I set up.